# Writing tutorials with exam document class, with and without solutions

Tags: exam

I would like to write some tutorials for my students, and for this I am using the `exam` document class, and the `solution` environment.

now the problem is I have a statement

```
\printanswers
```

that I need to comment for the tutorial, and uncomment for the solution.

I was hoping if there's a way through which I can compile it a single time, and the source file (say tutorial.tex) creates two pdfs -

1. tutorial.pdf (without solutions)
2. tutorialSolution.pdf (with solutions)

Following is my source code -

```
\documentclass{exam} 
%\printanswers
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{pslatex}
 \usepackage[pdftex]{color}  
 \usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}     

\begin{document}
\begin{questions}

\vskip 0.5 cm \question Question header \vskip 0.5cm
Question text

\begin{solution}
Solution text
\end{solution}

\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

thanks for any help you can provide.
gaurav

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. Have you considered either of the following possibilities? (1) Have two 'wrapper' `.tex` files with different names which call the main file, compiling the two wrappers to produce the two outputs. (2) Using a script rather than running the compilation directly either instead of, or in combination with, (1).

Comment: Hi, I must admit that I am a relative newbie when it comes to latex. Would it be possible for you to give a short example of compiling multiple files from a single main file? thanks in anticipation!

Comment: Why do you specify the driver for `color` and `graphicx`? Usually those packages are quite capable of detecting the right driver themselves...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I had in mind for one method you might use to manage this type of workflow.

You create 3 files. The first is your main file, `tutorial.tex`, say:

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{pslatex}
 \usepackage[pdftex]{color}  
 \usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}     

\begin{document}
\begin{questions}

\vskip 0.5 cm \question Question header \vskip 0.5cm
Question text

\begin{solution}
Solution text
\end{solution}

\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

The other two are wrappers. For example, these might be `tutorialQuestions.tex`:

```
\documentclass{exam} 
\input{tutorial}
```

and `tutorialSolutions.tex`:

```
\documentclass{exam} 
\printanswers
\input{tutorial}
```

You can then compile `tutorialSolutions.tex` and `tutorialQuestions.tex` separately without overwriting the other version. Or you could use a script to manage this for you. (How to do that depends on your OS.) It is also possible to use various helpers with TeX to do a lot of this and/or have your IDE automate things. However, the above is the basic idea which you then embed in the way that best suits your preferred tools.

Comment: cfr - thanks a lot! works like a charm. created a simple bash script to do the whole work and clean up afterwards too :)

Comment: @gaurav Excellent! I thought of this because I used it to create slides and an article version of logic exercises and it made it really simple to manage things. (I didn't bother scripting it but that is, of course, the way to do it properly!)

Answer (score 1):

While [cfr](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/39222/cfr)'s answer is very nice and general, I also ran into this problem and wanted to present a specific solution using one IDE, [TeXstudio](https://www.texstudio.org/).

To accomplish this, I defined a [user command](http://svn.code.sf.net/p/texstudio/code/trunk/utilities/usermanual_en.html#SECTION02a) (`Preferences > Build > User Commands`) as

```
"/path/to/script/compile-exam.py" %.tex -f | txs:///pdflatex | mv %.pdf %Solutions.pdf | mv %.synctex.gz %Solutions.synctex.gz | "/path/to/script/compile-exam.py" %.tex | txs:///pdflatex | txs:///view-pdf-internal "?m)Solutions.pdf"
```

where `compile-exam.py` is a python script I wrote (available [here](https://github.com/thompcinnamon/compile-exam)):

```python
from argparse import ArgumentParser
import re
from shutil import copyfile

parser = ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('filename')
parser.add_argument('-f', '--forward', action='store_true')

args = parser.parse_args()
copyfile(args.filename, args.filename+'.bak')

basename = re.match(r".+(?=\.tex)", args.filename).group(0)

if args.forward:
    contents = []
    with open(args.filename, 'r') as in_file:
        for line in in_file:
            if r'\printanswers' in line:
                contents.append('\printanswers\n')
            else:
                contents.append(line)
    with open(args.filename, 'w') as out_file:
        for line in contents:
            out_file.write(line)
else:
    contents = []
    with open(args.filename, 'r') as in_file:
        for line in in_file:
            if r'\printanswers' in line:
                contents.append('%\printanswers\n')
            else:
                contents.append(line)
    with open(args.filename, 'w') as out_file:
        for line in contents:
            out_file.write(line)
```

From here, I define a keyboard shortcut to run the command (`Preferences > Shortcuts > Tools > User`)

---

Using this keyboard shortcut, the compiler will produce `exam1.pdf` and `exam1Solutions.pdf` and display the Solutions file in the built-in viewer (still with the ability to scroll to the location of the last edit, etc.).

Also note, you will either need to call `python` first or make the script executable and add something like `#!/usr/bin/python` on the first line.

This is obviously not a general solution and does require calling an external program, but it works nicely and in a reasonable amount of time.